# Bound a Lyapunov storage function

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

How to effectively bound the following entity to deduce its definite negativeness
$\dot{v}  = -k_1 e_1^\top A e_1 + k_1 e_1^{\top} A e_2- k_2|e_2|^2$, with A a positive definite square matrix, $e_1$ and $e_2$ are vectors of the same size, and $k_1$ and $k_2$ are positive tuning gains?

Answer (score 0):

Show $$ k_1e_1^TAe_1 + k_2|e_2|^2 \geq k_1e_1^TAe_2 $$ or equally  $$ 2e_1^TAe_1 +  2k_2e_2^TIe_2 \geq 2 e_1^TAe_2, $$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. With $A = I = I^T>0$ and $k_2 = 1/4$ this inequality holds. Note that Young's inequality was applied, since $\alpha\,a^2 + \alpha^{-1} b^2 \geq 2ab$.

That means your time-derivative of the Lyapunov function $v$ is negative definite for $A = I$ and $k_2 = 1/4$, therefore, a bound must not calculated.

If $A$ is already specified and $A \ne I$ (then show what $A$ is), one may look for other choises of $k_1, k_2$, or even have to bound $e$. However, then also the differential equations should be given.